# Variable in model is not updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have the model that has $curent_day variable. When i try to update it`s value via Ajax, changeDay() returns new value, but getDay() called after changeDay() returns old value. What is wrong?

Controller

```
public function actionChangeDay($new_curent_day){
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $this->planing_model->curent_day = $new_curent_day;
        return $this->planing_model->curent_day;
    }
}

public function actionGetDay(){
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        return $this->planing_model->curent_day;
    }
}
```

Js

```
function changeDay(){
    $.get('/planing/change-day', {new_curent_day: $('.owl-item.center .slide_day').text()}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function getDay(){
    $.get('/planing/get-day', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: How are you calling those JS functions? Are you sure that the first call is finished before making the second call? If you're making them right after each other, the getDay() might actually make the request before the value have changed since those calls are async.

Comment: Yes, i can execute changeDay() few times, but getDay() will return the old value.

Comment: These functions are related to different elements

Comment: Do you actually save the updated model at any point? Every Ajax request is a brand new request to the server so if you change something in one call, it won't exist in the next, unless you have actually stored it and fetched it again in the next call. Every call is basically booting up everything from scratch.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the model is not saving. How can i do it?

Comment: how you create (and save) and retrieve the object where you store the value  ?? show thw related  action

Comment: public $planing_model;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->planing_model = new Planing();
    }

    public function actionPlaning(){

        $this->checkGroup();

        return $this->render('planing', ['planing_model'=>$this->planing_model]);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are assiggning the new model property but not saving it. After this:

```
$this->planing_model->curent_day = $new_curent_day;
```

Ypu should do this:

```
$this->planing_model->save();
```

Comment: planing_model extends Model, not ActiveRecord.

Comment: why not? ot's so much convenient.

Comment: this model is not working with db, it contains few variables like curent month, day, year etc., and their values generate in init() method

Comment: The, as you've been told, in each request the model is re-created with its initial values. If you do not persist them (in a db or smthng), you'll loose all data changed between requests

Comment: and there is no way to store it?

Comment: well, that is what databases are for :) if it's user-specific data, you could use the browser's session

Comment: i use it for dynamic calendar that looks like this: https://gyazo.com/5fb9509d3c8a809e585e3e24ac5d2e3b i use these variables - curent_day and curent_month to store chosen day and month. so, this variables should reset when user refresh page or go to other. how can i store it in session?

Comment: (1) Session data is conserved between requests within the same webapp, (2) https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies

Comment: It seems like exactly what i needed. Thanks you